# SQL satafile goes increasing and no space in physical drive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one table in datafile having size of 3.75 TB in SQL server 2008 R2.

only one table is there in that datafile and table size is same.

Is there any way, I can move my table data in another datafile which is located in other drive, without any change in current existing data in table.

Something like one table belongs from multiple datafiles, like I can give criteria as from this date data will be inserted on another drive datafile.

Notes: 
1. Table having cluster and non_cluster key
2. Table is in Peer to Peer replication

Comment: There are a lot of ways. Multiple data files, partitioning etc. This is covered in books and tutorials though, it's not related to programming at all. The common solution is to use a RAID array, **not** a single drive, and add drives to the array as needed.

Comment: Congratulations, you came up with the partitioning of tables :-). Fortunately, Microsoft knows about partitioning too. Read this tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730.aspx Separately, for replication of partitioned tables you can read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280940.aspx

Comment: @vitalygolub Thanks for the reply.
Any other option other than partitioning. As table is too large so I am having bit fear about table. I was looking for same table have other data file with date criteria in other drive, like from 1st April data will be store in other datafile which is in new drive ?

Comment: @Ragesh Sad, was so nice :-) Ok, create datafile in secondary filegroup on disk you want. Add table "myrelaibletable"  with keyword `ON NEW_FILGROUP_NAME` In result you will have new table **guaranteed** in newly created file and can add logic to your sql (of course, no automatic in this case, it can be just trigger to your main table) to preserve data in this table